# IoC - Unity, how RegisterInstance Works, Am I right?

Tags: .net, singleton, unity-container, ioc-container

I am implementing Ioc and there are few things i want to make sure are right.

1. If I use `RegisterInstance`, on resolving it will always return the singleton object?
2. BootStrapper will be loaded in **Global.asax** or some place where it will be loaded initially, which means all the instances will be singleton?

But i want to know how to
1. Create a separate instance per resolve, PerResolve wont work with RegisterInstance, it works only with RegisterType.
2. If I make dependent object as static property, it will work the same way, if i am able to create separate instance per resolve?

please help?

```
public class ClientUser : UserServiceBase, IClientUser
{
    private  IDataServiceManager _dataServiceManager;
    public ClientUser()
    {

    }

    private IDataServiceManager DataServiceMgr
    {
        get
        {
            if (_dataServiceManager == null)
                _dataServiceManager = ProjectContainer.Instance.Resolve<IDataServiceManager>();

            return _dataServiceManager;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't use `RegisterInstance` if you want PerResolve instancing. Either use `RegisterInstance` which will return always the same instance of the object (that is the point of registering instance) or use `RegisterType` and define `PerResolveLifetimeManager`.

`RegisterInstance` by default uses `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager`. The only other meaningfull lifetime manager for `RegisterInstance` is `ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager`.

`TransientLifetimeManager` and `PerResolveLifetimeManager` don't make sense because these lifetimes must create new instance each time you call `Resolve`.

`PerThreadLifetimeManager` is useless in scenarios where you don't control threading .

Comment: Thanks, just want to know one more thing, wats the best place to call bootstrapper for registeration?

Comment: You can place bootstrapper for example to Application_Start in global.asax.